# jquery tools overlay - Two on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay

I have been working with jquery tools overlays.  I got the below code online and have been able to make it work.  However I now need the overlay setup with another link on the same page and need a different size on that overlay.

I tried copying and pasting the code and changing the rel to look for an id.  My plan was the get a second function set to different div's, then setup the size in css.  I'm rather new to jquery and although I thought it would be easy I cannot figure this out.

If anyone has any better solutions please let me know.

```
$(function () {
        $("a[rel]").overlay({
            mask: 'lightgrey',
            effect: 'apple',
            onBeforeLoad: function () {
                var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
                wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
            }
        });
    });
```

I have tried changing $("a[rel]") to $("a.testclass") and $("#test"), but no other identifier seems to work.

Comment: this is not jQuery object ?

Comment: "Overlay" is not a jQuery function

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you include jQuery Tools in your HTML, like so:

```
 <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

That should make it work.

Comment: The code works fine.  What I'm failing to do it reuse it on another link with a different sized overlay.

Answer (score -1):

This is an [official jQuery homepage](http://jquery.com/). The API documentation is well organized. Search something about jQuery in this site.

`overlay()` doens't seem to be jQuery's default function. The function may be added like

```
$=jQuery;
$.fn.overlay=function(a, b, c){do something};
```

JavaScript [`eval("text")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function also do the job you want (maybe).